# Do we know why Nelson says "epidermis means your hair"?

Tags: the-simpsons

In [Bart of Darkness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bart_of_Darkness), we have the following dialogue starting with Bart standing on his treehouse:

[image: Bart standing on his treehouse]

> *Nelson*: Hey Bart, your epidermis is showing!
>
> *Bart*: It is? [Bart looks in vain for the problem, only to overbalance and fall from the treehouse, then screams with a girlish scream]
>
> *Nelson*: [talking to Kearney as Bart plummets] You see, **"epidermis" means your hair.** [Bart lands with a thud] So technically it's true; that's what makes it so funny.
> <sub>(Source: [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Simpsons/Season_6))</sub>

It's incorrect because

> ... epidermis is the outer layer of the three layers that make up the skin, the inner layers being the dermis and hypodermis.
> <sub>(Source: [Epidermis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidermis), Wikipedia)</sub>

What I'm curious about is why Nelson says this, as it seems just as funny if he said "epidermis means your skin" and more accurate.

**Question**: Do we know why Nelson says "epidermis means your hair"?

I'm wondering if this was intentional (it may have made the quote more well-known), or if it was just a mistake by the writers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The joke is that Nelson is playing a prank that depends on Bart’s ignorance of the word “epidermis”; but it turns out Nelson is just as ignorant as his target

Comment: We used this joke as kids in my school for a week or two.